# how to manage firewall settings on local rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, firewall, webrick, opentok

I'm trying to setup a basic OpenTok video connection between two osx computers on a local rails server. My second computer successfully connects to the local rails server, but the OpenTok video component does not work/tells me I have a firewall issue. I'm out of my depth on this network administration stuff. How would I investigate a possible firewall issue in this context? It's not blocking other computers' access but somehow interfering with the connection to OpenTok's servers.

Details:

I first tested my code on my own computer. Booted webrick with rails s, went to localhost:3000, my OSX built-in webcam connects, code works. Then opened a separate incognito tab in Chrome and loaded localhost again for a two-way connection. It all works. Great.

Then I tried booting with my internal IP (rails s -b 192.168.0.100) so that I could connect to the local server with a different computer. Server starts fine, I go to http://192.168.0.100:3000, my code works (e.g. I can login, page loads, etc) but the web cam video won't load (it's a blank black video screen with a loading icon, if that even matters). I connect to http://192.168.0.100:3000 from the other computer, code works but video won't load. Seems like an OpenTok issue. I load OpenTok's debug tool and sure enough there's an error on that session: "Failed to publish to session. This can happen if the user has denied access to the camera/microphone or if they are behind a firewall."

Clearly I had not denied camera/mic access, access was fine just a couple minutes ago on localhost, and no additional access prompts came up when I loaded http://192.168.0.100:3000. So I'm assuming there's firewall issue.

I tried booting on port 80 instead of 3000, also tried booting with 0.0.0.0, but keep running into the same error.

=====

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm pretty lost on this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if you meet all the requirements mentioned here: https://support.tokbox.com/hc/en-us/articles/203244520-OpenTok-Network-Connectivity-Requirements

Also, try running [Connectivity Doctor](http://tokbox.com/tools/connectivity/) in your Chrome/FF and see if that gives green checks.